# Webpack 5 and support for UNC paths as output?

Tags: webpack, fs, unc, webpack-5

If I set the `output.path` property of my webpack config to a UNC path like `\\COMPUTER-NAME\some-share` I get the following error since webpack 5 (It used to work in webpack 4):

```
C:\Temp\dbp\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\fs.js:121
                throw new Error(
                ^
Error: \\COMPUTER-NAME\some-share is neither a posix nor a windows path, and there is no 'join' method defined in the file system
    at join (C:\Temp\dbp\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\fs.js:121:9)
    at C:\Temp\dbp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:790:31
    at arrayIterator (C:\Temp\dbp\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3467:9)
    at timesSync (C:\Temp\dbp\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2297:7)
    at Object.eachLimit (C:\Temp\dbp\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3463:5)
    at emitFiles (C:\Temp\dbp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:536:13)
    at C:\Temp\dbp\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\fs.js:182:5
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:171:23)
```

I looked in to the join method if `node_modules\webpack\lib\util\fs.js:121:9` and it looks like:

```
/**
 * @param {InputFileSystem|OutputFileSystem|undefined} fs a file system
 * @param {string} rootPath a path
 * @param {string} filename a filename
 * @returns {string} the joined path
 */
const join = (fs, rootPath, filename) => {
    if (fs && fs.join) {
        return fs.join(rootPath, filename);
    } else if (rootPath.startsWith("/")) {
        return path.posix.join(rootPath, filename);
    } else if (rootPath.length > 1 && rootPath[1] === ":") {
        return path.win32.join(rootPath, filename);
    } else {
        throw new Error(
            `${rootPath} is neither a posix nor a windows path, and there is no 'join' method defined in the file system`
        );
    }
};
```

From what I can tell here it seems like if the input fs does not have a join method a UNC path will not work.

I'm not sure what the input fs params will be. I'm testing this on a windows system and I guess this function is not there...

Should UNC paths be supported?

Comment: I'm having the same error.